# Cannot specialize non-generic type 'Set'

Tags: ios, swift, nsmanagedobject

This is my `NSManagedObject`:

```
@objc(Order)
class Order: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var orderItems: Set<OrderItem> //error: Cannot specialize non-generic type 'Set'
}
```

Anyone know why it doesnt work?

`OrderItem` file is created and works however for following declaration:

```
@NSManaged var orderItem: OrderItem
```

Comment: Works fine in a playground with Xcode 7.3.1, which version of Swift are you using?

Comment: The same Xcode, how to check version of Swift?

Comment: xcrun swift -version

Comment: Currently I use 2.2

Comment: Here too, btw, i tested with an Int instead of OrderItem.

Comment: Don't have another `Set` type in your project?

Comment: Oh, yes, you are awesome, I have another type of `Set`. You saved my life;)

Comment: Nope and tested with a set of classes, it works too: http://pastebin.com/S3kN2fCK

Comment: How can I differ them now? `UIKit.Set<OrderItem>`?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use it like that providing the fully qualified name of the class.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake: `Swift.Set<OrderItem>`:)

Comment: Yes, that should refer to the language provided one.

Answer (score 8):

Just for reference if someone should come to this question in the future for this nasty bug, since the discussion went on in the comments.

Yes, the default `Set` type in Swift is generic, but in this case a custom non-generic `Set` class was shadowing the class defined by the language's standard library.

Better always choose different names for your classes, to avoid name clashes. But if needed, you can always use the fully qualified name of the classes to refer to the class you want.

Standard language classes are available under the `Swift.` namespace, while for other classes you can use the name of the module followed by a dot and the name of the class (e.g. Foundation.NSString).